# Alert "Sign in to iTunes Store" and "Battery low" pauses my apps jams. How can I unpause them?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I have some music in my app that plays under `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`. Right now my problem is that when a popup from Apple like "Sign in to iTunes Store" pops up it pauses my music, but does not resume it. Thankfully it takes care of my `SKScene`... but not the music. Is there some way to have a callback for when the alert is dismissed?

The weird thing is that other `UIAlertView`s that I have made don't do this to the app, so I really don't know what is up.

List of alerts that pause scene and music:

- Login to itunes
- Battery low
- Confirm purchase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problems sometime ago (beginning of Swift 1.2). I solved my problem by observing **paused** status for SKScene. SKScene have view which is SKView type.

```
private var queueContext = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    self.view.addObserver(self,
                          forKeyPath: "paused",
                          options: .New,
                          context: &queueContext)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if context == &queueContext {
        if let paused = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? Bool {
            // TODO: react on paused status changes
        }
    }
    else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: wait a moment though.  This is crashing issues with transitions, specifically when .presentScene() is called. Unfortunately the error is ambiguous.  And only happens when I move onto the 3rd scene.  Any ideas?

Comment: @J.Doe What type of crash do you getting? Crash stack?

Comment: Unfortunately it came with no stack! However I figured out the problem! I didn't know view controllers had a self.view property, and thus I thought this was supposed to go in each scene.  Turns out putting it in the view controller and not in scenes fixed it!

Comment: Do you have to like unlisten for events or something?

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

Add a key-value observe on the player's `rate` property.  When rate changes (the system `UIAlertController` stops the audio, start playback again.

For StoreKit transactions: I believe you can get and set callbacks for a successful or unsuccessful `SKPaymentTransaction` state.  In these callbacks, start audio playback once more.  This doesn't account for the low battery case though.